# Is it possible to require multiple strong params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do some server-side validation for a form in Rails, and I would like to require specific fields to have a value. Here are the params in my controller:

```
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :slug)
end
```

The problem is that the server merely *permits* these params — it doesn't require them, so it's possible to submit a completely blank form.

My understanding is that `params.require` only accepts one argument, and I've tried getting around this with no success:

```
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post, :title, :text, :slug)
end
# => wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)

private
def post_params
  all_params = [:post, :title, :text, :slug]
  params.require(all_params)
end
# => param is missing or the value is empty: [:post, :title, :text, :slug]

private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).require(:title).require(:text).require(:slug)
end
# => private method `require' called for "test thing":String
```

Is there any way to require multiple strong params?

Comment: I can't understand your point. If you are using validations(like presence) on at least one of those attributes, you can't even submit a form with blank values.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem to me. What's wrong with using a `presence: true` clause in your model's validations? I don't have any models which accept blank forms, yet I haven't modified my strong params to require more than one object, ever...

Comment: @MarsAtomic Derp… looks like I was going about this the wrong way. I had forgotten about model validations, so I was trying to require params instead. I added validations, and all is well now. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strong Parameters are used for mass assignment. What does mass assignment means is that when you submit a form multiple values are submitted i.e., multiple attributes of a model so you add them in the `params.require(:post).permit`. You are seeing the word `permit` which means this attributes are permitted to be mass assigned. Now suppose you are writing this in controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :slug)
end
```

and in your params suppose you have:

```
{"post"=>{"title"=>'Test',"text"=>"Text test","slug"=>"any random name","type"=>"article"}}
```

Now if you do:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.save
```

It will give you `unpermitted parameters :type` because you have not whitelisted the `type` parameter. This is given for security reasons so that you only allow attributes that needs to be updated by user from the view are permitted. And the strong parameters are introduced from rails 4 onwards.

Now the thing you need to require these parameters that the user fills them so this needs to be done in the model like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :text, :slug
end
```

This is a validation which will make the users enter the `title, text and slug` necessarily. There are more type of validations and some custom validations too which can be written according to the needs.

More Info:

[Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

[Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Just figured this out. Thanks so much!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, he asked how to add multiple strong parameters, not for an explanation of the strong params concept

Comment: @rails_has_elegance If I am not wrong the OP didn't understand the use of strong params, he was mixing validations with strong params that is why I have added an explanation of strong params, if you feel it is not correct then please go ahead and post the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer is definitely useful as it hints that instead of using param.require for validations, this should be done inside the model with a validates_presence_of or presence: true, however, I feel like it doesn't address the fact that the params.require concept in rails is pretty confusing, since it only accepts 1 parameter. Yes, in your example, the attributes are nested within the post param, but whenever your params are flat and not nested, and you want to require multiple of them, rails' strong params concept is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

Strong params is not (and cannot) be used for validating the presence of attributes. As @Deep said you use the validate presence for that.

The academic question remains how to require multiple strong params, the word 'params' is misleading here as the 'require' part specifies the key of the attribute hash. The reason require only accepts one is because typically a form is submitted with an attribute hash representing a single object - nesting aside.

In theory though, if your params hash looked contained these key/value pairs:

```
... this: { name: 'this', number: 1 }, that: { color: 'red', size: 'big'} ...
```

You might legitimately want to do requires for both this: and that: and permit attributes for them independently, if so you could do this:

```
def this_and_that_params
  { this: params.require(:this).permit(:name), that: params.require(:that).permit(:color) }
end
```

which would return:

```
... this: { name: 'this' }, that: { color: 'red' } ...
```