# How to require and permit multiple strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I try for hours now to only "permit" the following params-hash in the controller:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "article"=>{
    "title"=>"Titel Tags",
    "text"=>"Tags Tags Tags"
  },
  "tags"=>{
    "name"=>"ufos, foo, bar, aerzte"
  },
  "commit"=>"Create Article"
}
```

My approach is with `tap`

```
def article_params
params.tap { |article_params| article_params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)}.tap {|tags_params| tags_params.require(:tags).permit(:name) }
end
```

Output is still, that the parameters are not permitted - so I can't use the input from the view in my controller at all, even though the hash is set up fine.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DuMUDfPFe6iFq2Jwj4gTst1nFI3JVwTCoXu/oL53TxE1cXhtK1d+WOBL4U7A3Efo2sGxr7RCHLx3LTau7SK0xg==", "article"=><ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"Titel Tags", "text"=>"Tags Tags Tags"} permitted: false>, "tags"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"ufos, foo, bar, aerzte"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Create Article", "controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

What is it that I am obviously doing horribly wrong and against the rails way? I thought using `tap` would be darn smart an approach but obviously not smart enough for "cracking the rails code". :)

Help needed !

Comment: Try with `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text); params.require(:tags).permit(:name)` (two lines).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. But that would only lead to the last statement to persist. The first one doesn't persist.

The output is ```<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"ufos, foo, baz, bar"} permitted: true>``` and it lacks the nesting ```"tags" => { "name" => "ufos, foo", ... ``` as well as ```articles``` of course.

Yours sincerely

von Spotz

Comment: Is it 'tags' nested under article?

Comment: No, they are "side by side"

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But now it is :tags that is not "permitted"

```>> 

article_params

=> <ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"Params permit test", "text"=>"Test params permit"} permitted: true>```

Meanwhile I had success with ```{ :article => article_whitelist }.merge ({ :tags => tags_whitelist})``` but I don't have any trust this "success" is anywhere lege artis. It's more of some kind of a hack.

Comment: Where ```article_whitelist = params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)```

and

```tags_whitelist = params.require(:tags).permit(:name)```

Comment: `require` can take array of keys `params.require([:article, :tags])`

Comment: Hello Mosaaleb,

yes, but how could one then assign the fields :title and :text to :article on one side and :name to :tags on the other one?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried permitting all the values inside both article and tags?

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64720708) and [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/rails-strong-parameters-how-to-permit-and-require-multiple-params/256110/3)?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
def article_params
  params.permit(
    :utf_8,
    :authenticity_token,
    :commit,
    tags: [:name],
    article: [:title,:text]
  )
end
```

This is works for me.