# Rails declare multiple required parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I'm receiving request from the external API. I want to check if the incoming request is valid. To do so I've to use strong parameters, here is the sample JSON request which hit my endpoint:

```
  "sdd_request": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "data": {
      "debit_method": "CORE",
      "debtor": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        }
      },
      "extension": {
        "signees": [{email: 'test@test.com', name: 'joe', last_name: 'smith' }],
        "creditor": {
          "id": "12345",
          "name": "Acme Inc.",
          "address": {
            "city": "New York",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So the required are:

```
- return_url
- data
- signees
- creditor
```

How to require above parameters?

What I did was:

```
  def sdd_setup_request_params
    params.require(:sdd_request).permit(
      :return_url,
      data: [
        :debit_method,
        debtor: [
          :name,
          :email,
          ]
        ],
        extension: [
          signees: [],
          creditor: [
            :id,
            :name,
            address: [
              :city,
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    )
  end
```

But from what I understand that required whole object of `sdd_request` not individual components because if e.g. `signees` are missing it will nor raise an error of missing parameters am I right?

Comment: You've added your new rules as `permit`. Did you try adding them as `require`?

Comment: Yes, if I do something like this: `params.permit(:sdd_request, :return_url).premit(:return_url,( ...))` I'll get `ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))`

Answer (score 1):

The role of strong parameters is not to validate the data. It's just to whitelist the parameters to avoid mass assignment vulnerabilities.

`require` is used to bail early if the general structure of the parameters makes it pointless to continue processing the request. Like for example in your typical Rails controller:

```
params.require(:person)
      .permit(:name, :age, :city)
```

There is no point in continuing to process the request if the key `:person` is missing so a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception is raised which Rails rescues and returns a `400 - Bad Request` response.

This prevents the potential nil errors that could occur when you expect a hash and get nil instead.

[Validating the presence of the actual attributes is the job of the model in Rails.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#why-use-validations-questionmark)

```ruby
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :name
  attribute :age
  attribute :city
  validates :name, :age, :city, presence: true
end
```

You might be thinking now: *But waaaah I don't have a model because I'm gettting it from an API and I'm not saving it*. Models can still be really useful even without persistence since the represent the entities in your application in a normalized form.

If you still really want to avoid a model for whatever reason there are gems that provide model-less validation in the controller with a bit more grace then a web of `if` statements.

While you can use `require` on nested hash structures like JSONAPI.org this will just return a single key and will raise on the first missing key so it cannot be used to give meaningful detailed feedback about whats wrong with the input.

```ruby
params.require(:data)
      .require(:attributes)
      .permit(:name, :age, :city)
```

Comment: The guides article tilts really heavily towards ActiveRecord but all the validations except `validates_uniqueness` are actually in ActiveModel now and are just as relevant when you're not persisting the data.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64720708) and [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/rails-strong-parameters-how-to-permit-and-require-multiple-params/256110/3)?

Comment: @user502052 what's your point?